# Background image stick to the footer

Tags: html, css, background-image

How can I make my background image sticks always to the bottom of the page. [This](http://healinghands.vtable.us/board-of-directors/) is the page where I have the issue. I am attaching an image to the body and my CSS is

```
html {
height:100%;
     }

body {
background: #fff url(images/bg.png) repeat-x;
-moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
color: #404040;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-smoothing: antialiased;
line-height: 1.5em;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
body {
  background-attachment: fixed; /* stick it */
  background-position: bottom;  /* to the bottom */
}
```

Comment: I just tried fixed and it works well but the blue area covers almost 70% of my page. Is there another way? My designer told me she wants to have the same feeling as you see now in home page but  in all pages

Comment: Make a smaller image, or play with `background-position` to push it down

Answer (score 0):

Use: `background-position: bottom left;`